# Ping iPhone address, response is off

Tags: iphone, macos, bash, shell, ping

I try ping to iPhone address with shell (on mac osx), but if iPhone is in standby after 3 min the result is: no Ping, iPhone is offline!

How I check if iPhone is online on my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I check if iPhone is online on my network?

E.g.

```
arp -a
```

or

```
ping "$ip"
```

Combine it with a loop maybe.

Comment: thank you! I try to combine ping & arp and I solve my problem!!!